# Can you say "Wie du magst." by itself as a way of saying "as you wish/prefer"?

Tags: meaning

Is this correct and if so, is it seen as impolite? I'm looking for a friendly way of saying "as you want" in conversation when speaking to someone and they've suggested several ways of doing something where I really don't mind which option we take.

Comment: I'm not sure that "as you want" would be the way one would say this in English. If there are several options then "prefer" is a more fitting verb. Also, "as" usually means a manner of doing something rather than an option, so I suppose it depends on what kind of options are being given. It should be noted that English as at least one unfriendly way saying this, "Whatever," though much depends on the tone of voice. It's normally used by disgruntled teenagers in the sense of "We'll end up doing it your way anyway, so why are you bothering to ask me?"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, "wie du magst" or "wie du möchtest" or "ich richte mich da gerne nach dir" are good ways of saying it.

You could make sure to also state that you don't mind because that's not implied. ("Mir ist es egal", "Mir ist beides recht", "ich finde beides gut", "Ich finde alle Vorschläge gut")

Uttering "Von mir aus." would be a reaction to a single suggestion, and would mean "I'm not really happy with it, but I'm ok to concede." However, "Von mir aus können wir das gern machen." is perfectly polite.

How all of this is perceived always also depends on context, like in any language. You can probably also give nonverbal clues about how you mean it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the more natural way would be "wie du willst" - as you want

you can also say "von mir aus" which would be like "doesn't matter to me"

Comment: These versionsare possible, however, they are not that polite.

Answer (score 1):

The politest way of translating it in colloquial terms would be „Wie du möchtest“. If the sentence shall stand alone, you could also say „Ganz wie du möchtest.“
The politest term (although it sounds a bit archaic) might be „Wie Sie wünschen“.

Answer (score 0):

"Wie Du magst" even though translating as "How(ever) you like (it)" has a risk of being understood as "suit yourself" or even "Whatever" and those are not very friendly terms. Since you're apparently already Dooching, "Wie Du möchtest" ("As you (would) want") takes the edge off. Not so when Seeching. "Wie Sie möchten" gets stepped up to "Wie Sie wünschen" which translates as "As you wish" which means the same, but with less risk to be misinterpreted, due to its more respectful and humble attitude. All these can be said by themselves.